# Users can't find our app in the apple appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

We recently published an app to the german Apple AppStore. Some of our users are reporting a strange behaviour when they search for our app (Couponiac). The search shows no result. But when they use our developer acc name (Couponiac UG) the app shows up.

Comment: When did you push it? I think you will have to wait for an (undetermined) period of time for it to become available on searches. Server caches prevent it from being immediately visible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392760/application-not-in-the-app-store-search

Answer (score 0):

While facing such issue there can be few possible reasons. Here it is:

- First thing is after application approved & ready for sale it can take some time to come into search results
- Second thing is if the application name or a part of you application name already taken by some of the apps who already on the app store from long time than it might not show you in results or it can show very far down the page
- Make sure if they try to use full name of your application & search & see if shows or not. If it shows while searching with full name & not with the partial name of the app than you should wait for some amount of downloads of the app. Once your application downloads will be increased it will automatically up & will start showing on initial results

I hope it will guide you.

Comment: OK, so we will wait for a while. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NilsFuchs all the best