# App not found on appStore Search

Tags: ios, itunes

My app status is Ready for Sale, but not found in the Appstore search less, all aspects of the check, and did not find the problem? Is this appStore's problem?
My app is not first sale !!

Comment: There are lots of answer regarding this... please search before asking question  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392760/application-not-in-the-app-store-search

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application not in the App Store Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392760/application-not-in-the-app-store-search)

Answer (score 0):

I was upload app on App Store more than one week ago. It was ready for sale on next day. But after so many days it’s not showing on App Store and not searchable on google.Before 10 days It started showing ready for sale.Its available on App Store link at itunesconnect.

Comment: Could not get your comments. Please be elaborative.

Comment: My app is ready for sale from last 10 days. But it is not showing on App Store and not searchable on google search engine. because when we search any app that is live on App Store that always show on google.