# iOS 11 App Store my app doesn‘t appear in search

Tags: ios, app-store

why doesn’t appear my app in the iOS 11 App Store on my iPhone? It is released to the App Store and iTunes Connect says that it is available. If I try to open the app via direct link it will appear, but it does not via search...

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi Markus  click on "View on App Store" which is present under "Additional Information"  in Itunesconnect AppInformation it may help you out in some time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application not in the App Store Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392760/application-not-in-the-app-store-search)

Comment: @AyushYadav Thank you. I did that. But other Users can't do that.

Comment: @markus - after clicking on that it may available for user in some time.Actually i faced same before.

Comment: @AyushYadav OK, thank you for this Information. I'll wait a few hours. Maybe the App will be visible then. :)

Comment: in iTunes Connect, when your app status become **Ready For Sale** ? because after ready for sale status it will available in 8-10 hours into app store.

Comment: @NiravKotecha Yes, it is in Status "Ready for Sale".

Comment: when this status comes ? means at what time ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha Today, 0:40 MESZ.

Comment: apple have not given perfect time but it will take normally 8-10 hours after ready for sale and then you can find in app store

Comment: @NiravKotecha OK, thank you. :)

Comment: @MarkusTippner is it available in app store now ? can you see it ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha Yes, it is. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392760/application-not-in-the-app-store-search) similar Stack Overflow question, it can take a while for the App Store to index your newly published application in their search engine and across servers worldwide.

App Store listings are ranked on the popularity of the app, which is based on the number of downloads, number of ratings, and numerous other statistics kept secret by Apple.

The name and keywords provided on iTunes Connect also impact the visibility of your app. Depending on popularity and similarly named applications, your new app could rank behind more popular, generic application names.